# String Match for classifying comments when they meet a specific pattern of words

Tags: r, regex, string

Hello guys I hope everyone is doing well.

I'd like to know how to properly classify a new variable based in a pattern string match that has to contain certain words.

Lets say I have this Data that contains some n number of comments

```
data<-c("Alex is not working", "Britney is working", "Kelly Worked", "Nina IS NOT working")
```

I'd like to classify those comments that contain the letter working AND the letter not even is those words are in uppercase or lowercase form.

I am trying to use this code:

```
ifelse(grepl("working|not", data), "MATCH", "NOT_A_MATCH")
```

but I get:

```
"MATCH" "MATCH" "MATCH" "MATCH"
```

I know this is because the (|) operator is OR but when I use (&) or AND I get an undesired answer.

What I want is:

```
"MATCH" "NOT_A_MATCH" "NOT_A_MATCH" "MATCH"
```

Thank you guys SO MUH for your help

Comment: Ok, you need `stringr::str_detect(data, "(?i)^(?=.*\\bnot\\b)(?=.*\\bworking\\b)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifelse(grepl("^(?=.*working)(?=.*not)", data, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE),
       "MATCH", "NOT A MATCH")
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. I think the easiest way is to use `ifelse()` with `grepl()`, and `toupper()` to convert everything to upper case:

```
> ifelse(grepl("WORKING", toupper(data)) & grepl("NOT", toupper(data)), "MATCH", "NOT_A_MATCH")
[1] "MATCH" "NOT_A_MATCH" "NOT_A_MATCH" "MATCH"
```

Comment: Hey! Never heard of that fun before toupper.. I will be giving it a look"! I am learning and this is so cool to find new ways to do things thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
ifelse(grepl("not working", data, ignore.case = T), "MATCH", "NOT_A_MATCH")
[1] "MATCH"       "NOT_A_MATCH" "NOT_A_MATCH" "MATCH"
```

Comment: This is great Thank you so much I will give it a try! thanks again